# UILabel sizetofit hides some words in the attributed text

Tags: html, ios, swift, string, uilabel

An attributed text is set to an UILabel.

```
let label = UILabel()
label.frame = view.frame
label.numberOfLines = 0
do {
    let spannableString = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
    label.attributedText = spannableString
} catch {
    print(error)

}
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
label.sizeToFit()
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Some of the texts are not visible. ie, Some words in the end of the text are truncating/not visible. Attributed text is formed from the below HTML String.

```
<span style="line-height&#58;1.4em;">HE Ahmed Mohamed Al Humairi, Secretary General of MoPA and Chairman of the Emirates Palace Company (EPCo), held a meeting attended by the board members and the General Manager of the Emirates Palace hotel. &#160;In the course of the meeting, a committee was formed to prepare for the 42nd National Day celebrations in a style that will highlight the importance of such a national event and reflect the culturally-developed status of Abu Dhabi. &#160;</span><br><div><br></div><div>The meeting also reviewed the latest developments in the ongoing projects aimed at maintaining the pioneering role played by the Emirates Palace in being both one of the best hotels in the world and one of the most important metropolitan landmarks in Abu Dhabi. &#160;</div><div><br></div><div>The board discussed a set of new projects and future events that will serve to enhance the role of the Emirates Palace Hotel in helping to stimulate tourism and the economy. &#160;</div>
```

I'd tried adding a vertical constraint

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label,
                                               attribute: .centerY,
                                               relatedBy: .equal,
                                               toItem: self.view,
                                               attribute: .centerY,
                                               multiplier: 1.0,
                                               constant: 0.0))
```

But no luck. Can anyone suggest a solution for this issue?

Comment: can you post image of the problem and your requirement we are able to get all the text visible in label

Comment: without this `<span style="line-height&#58;1.4em;">` i used `<span>` and I tried your code , i got full answer

Comment: @Anbu.karthik, that span style is needed. With that, any solutions please?

Comment: @Anbu.karthik, thanks for your suggestions, from your old answer I got an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting attributed text to label, simple text does the trick by getting string from `attributedString`

```
do {
    let spannableString = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
    label.text = spannableString.string
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `xAxis` Position of your `UILabel` object in order to make visible on screen.

```
//Taking Leading Constraint as X-Axis constraint.

self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label,
                                               attribute: .leading,
                                               relatedBy: .equal,
                                               toItem: self.view,
                                               attribute: .leading,
                                               multiplier: 1.0,
                                               constant: 0.0))
```